# Cocos2dx - Socket.io onConnect never being called

Tags: socket.io, cocos2d-x

I'm using Cocos2dx and Socket.io , after the connection the delegate method `onConnect` never being called.

I see the log `SIODelegate event 'connect' fired with data:`
but everything i write on the `onConnect` method never being execute.